# Getting Powershell return code within a .BAT program

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a .BAT program where I'm calling a Powershell script to run.

How I can get the exit code in the .BAT program when the powershell finishes its work?

EDIT:

This has worked for me.

```
call powershell.exe .\MyPowerShellScript.ps1
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: That works, but there seems to be a more intuitive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable will give you the last return code:

```
@echo off

call powershell.exe -Command "exit 123"
echo Exited with return code %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Will result in:

```
C:\> path\to\script.bat
Exited with return code 123
```

With a script, either use the `-File` parameter:

```
@echo off

call powershell.exe -File "path\to\file.ps1"
echo Exited with return code %ERRORLEVEL%
```

or use the `&` call operator to invoke the script:

```
@echo off

call powershell.exe -Command "& 'C:\path\to\file.ps1'"
echo Exited with return code %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just a bit confused on where we would put the ps1 file in the command. This worked for me:

call powershell.exe .\MyPowerShellScript.ps1
echo %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: @rlima1877 You'd do `-File path\to\file.ps1` instead :)

Comment: Sorry I'm a total noob and didn't realize that the -Command was a placeholder for the -File path\to\file.ps1

Comment: Call is only for returning from other .bat scripts.

Comment: @js2010 old habit, doesn't really matter in this case

Answer (score 1):

A script terminating exception will also set the errorlevel.

```
powershell throw

ScriptHalted
At line:1 char:1
+ throw
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptHalted


echo %errorlevel%

1
```